# merge two datasets same column name into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to merge two datasets

table1:

```html
id date a
1 2020-01-01 1
2 2020-01-02 4
3 2020-01-04 3
4 2020-01-25
```

table 2

```html
id date a b
    1 2020-01-01  0.1
    2 2020-01-02  0.2
    3 2020-01-04  0.3
    4 2020-01-25 5 0.25
```

the expected output is

```html
id date a b
    1 2020-01-01 1 0.1
    2 2020-01-02 4 0.2
    3 2020-01-04 3 0.3
    4 2020-01-25 5 0.25
```

I use the merge function,and set all.x=True,the result still generate a.x and a.y columns.Does it have any way to combine a.x and a.y into only one column? The A column value from two table will not overlap each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `coalesce` to merge the `a` values in the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

table1 %>%
  inner_join(table2, by = c('id', 'date')) %>%
  mutate(a = coalesce(a.x, a.y)) %>%
  select(-a.x, -a.y)

#  id       date    b a
#1  1 2020-01-01 0.10 1
#2  2 2020-01-02 0.20 4
#3  3 2020-01-04 0.30 3
#4  4 2020-01-25 0.25 5
```

In base R that would be -

```
transform(merge(table1, table2, by = c('id', 'date')), 
                a = ifelse(is.na(a.x), a.y, a.x))[names(table2)]
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
table1 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", 
"2020-01-04", "2020-01-25"), a = c(1L, 4L, 3L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

table2 <- structure(list(id = 1:4, date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", 
"2020-01-04", "2020-01-25"), a = c(NA, NA, NA, 5L), b = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.25)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```